# Como criar uma table no hana workbench by column?

Tags: erp

Estou utilizando o SAP Hana workbench pelo navegador e preciso criar uma table by 'column', mas não sei como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "NOMEDATABELA" ("ID" INTEGER CS_INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL ,
"ID" INTEGER CS_INT,
"NOME" NVARCHAR(50),
"IDADE" INTEGER CS_INT,
PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
```